# New webpage needs to close previous page

Tags: angularjs, web, angular-ui-router

I'm working with a hospital where we are implementing a web-application that is triggered from their own hospital information system (HIS).
The way the app works is that in their HIS, they select a patient and call the web-app with the patientId in the url.

Regarding patient safety, they want only one of those tabs open at the same time.
So if a second patient-tab is opened, the first one should be closed ..

Is this possible? And if it is, how?

#### Edit following `danday74`'s answer

The url from the HIS is triggered via command line arguments (SAP system).

```
Firefox "http://url_to_webpage/"
```

Comment: No need to create a new tag for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for the people that have a similar problem, the way we fixed it was the following:

- On the init script for the page, we check if a session variable `tab-token` is found and if it contains a UUID
- If the variable is not found, it means that no other open tab is found and we leave the tab active + create the variable and store a generated UUID in it
- If a UUID is found, that means another tab is also active and we show a screen overlay with the message that another active tab was found

We watch on every change in the session variable and update the screen overlay whenever and wherever it needs to.

It is not a fool-proof solution, but in the context and usage of the application, it is sufficient ..

Answer (score 0):

when you link to the patient tab do this ...

```
<a ng-href="/your/patient/url" target="patientTab">open new patient tab</a>
```

When the link is clicked it should open the page in a new tab called "patientTab" - if another link is clicked with the target patientTab then it will use the existing "patientTab" - just make sure all your anchor tags that use the patientTab have the target set.

hope that does the job for you :)

Comment: Other than the fact that i didn't know that (thanks! ;-) ), it doesn't help me :-( The url is triggered via command line arguments .. i shall update the original question.